# Empty Area when left click and drag on page

Tags: html, css

I have a weird problem on my website. My website looks ok when I load it. when I click and drag on an area on my page to the right, all the page moves left and I get an empty space on the right.

Screenshot:

[image]

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Verdana, Tahoma, Arial;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


#wrap {
    width: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    text-align: left;
}

#header {
    width: 190px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
}

#main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 100px;
}

#scrollable {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 0;
}

.scrollableArea {
    position: relative;
 }
```

HTML Skeleton:

```
  <body> 
 <div id="wrap">
        <div id="page">
         <div id="header"></header>
         <div id="main"></div>
        </div>
 </div>
 <div id="scrollable" class="holder">
   <div id="scrollableWrapper" ></div>
   <div id="scrollableArea" ></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Hope that I've given all the information needed. Just can't seem to solve this. I think it's related to the scrollable div. The ScrollableArea can be much larger than the viewport and extend beyond the screen limit but it's invisible and will not show scroll.

Thanks.

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net and try to replicate there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove: `body { overflow-x: hidden; }`

Comment: Thanks. This actually helped me solve the problem and see the DIV that causes the problem. Thanks a million.